# Android: How to properly align this text in the layout and ensure it works across different devices?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, textview

Image of the layout issue [HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M9Bfx.jpg).

I am running into a small issue setting up the layout properly.  I would like to align the label text "Time Left" and "Score" below their counterparts. How can I also ensure that the layout works for different screen sizes. Currently I am hardcoding padding to adjust the text and try to center it but I don't think thats the best way.  I've also attached my xml code.

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/timer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
        android:paddingLeft="50dp"
        android:text="0"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lbl_timer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/timer"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
        android:paddingLeft="50dp"
        android:text="Time Left"
        android:textColor="#000" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lbl_score"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/score"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingRight="50dp"
        android:text="Score"
        android:textColor="#000" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/score"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
        android:paddingRight="50dp"
        android:text="0"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Solution:**

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/fragment_container"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/timerLL"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="50"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/timer"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="0"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lbl_timer"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/timer"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Time Left"
            android:textColor="#000" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@id/timerLL"
        android:layout_weight="50"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/score"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="0"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lbl_score"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/score"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Score"
            android:textColor="#000" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably wrap each in a `LinearLayout` with vertical `orientation`. Then center them. Something like this ought to work, though I haven't tested it...

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/fragment_container">
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/timerLL"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/timer"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
    android:text="0"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/lbl_timer"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/timer"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
    android:text="Time Left"
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center" />
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignToRightOf="@id/timerLL"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/lbl_score"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/score"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
    android:text="Score"
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/score"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
    android:text="0"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center" />
</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Also note that `RelativeLayout` doesn't have the `orientation` property so I took that out...not a problem just an FYI. I have made some edits and tested. This should get you close and look similar on most devices. Though you may change some properties as needed to get the specific look you want.

Comment: Thanks! I modified your solution and added a LinearLayout as the root and made use of layout_weight to get the right look.

Comment: Glad I could help and glad you were able to modify *yourself* to *your* specifications. :)

Answer (score 1):

Use LayoutMargins instead of Padding. You still have to hard code values but these values will go by the dpi of the device for spacing. and look the same across all.